# Find a sequnce $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\in l_2$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n/\sqrt{n} = \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

As stated in title, I am curious how to construct a sequnce $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2 < +\infty$ but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}} = \infty$.

This problem arises when I try to show that $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ defined on $l_2$ space is not bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\ln(n+1)}$$

Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln(n+1)^2}<\infty$$

but

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln(n+1)}=\infty$$

Comment: Great minds, yadda yadda.

Answer (score 2):

Try $a_n = (\sqrt{n}\log(n))^{-1},$ for $n\geq 2$.